# Need to find the number of records in a difference between 10 years in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My dataset has date of birth starting from 1900 till 2017 . I wanted to see  the record count in the gap of 10 years . Example : The output should look like this :
FromYearToYear  count
1900-1910        100 
1910-1920        200  .

Any help will be really appreciated .

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please show us your effort !!!

Comment: Where do you count people who were born in 1910 (say)? In the interval 1900-1910 or in the interval 1910-1920? Or in both - resulting in them being counted twice? (This is simply a way to point out that the problem as stated doesn't make sense - before thinking of ANY solution to it.)

Answer (score 0):

One way  would be to extract the year, divide it by 10, floor it, and multiply by 10 and group by that

```
--test data
create table a ( MY_DATE DATE ) ;
insert into a select to_date('01-01-1900','DD-MM-YYYY')+dbms_random.value(1,40000) from dual connect by level < 5000;

--example of grouping
select  '['||
         FLOOR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_DATE)/10)*10||'-'||
         ((FLOOR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_DATE)/10)*10)+10)||'[', 
         COUNT(*) 
FROM a GROUP BY FLOOR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_DATE)/10)*10
order by FLOOR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_DATE)/10)*10
```

or with truncs

```
select '['||
        trunc(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_DATE),-1)||'-'||(trunc(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_DATE),-1)+10)||'[', 
        COUNT(*)
FROM a GROUP BY trunc(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_DATE),-1)
order by trunc(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_DATE),-1)
```

result :

```
RANGE       CNT
[1900-1910[ 2518
[1910-1920[ 3882
[1920-1930[ 884
[1930-1940[ 944
[1940-1950[ 867
[1950-1960[ 909
[1960-1970[ 936
[1970-1980[ 912
[1980-1990[ 896
[1990-2000[ 917
[2000-2010[ 903
```

Please take note of @Mathguy's important comment. I Added the symbols before and after the range to specify that lower bound is included and upper one is excluded.

Edit : Changed the rounding by floor following @ Wernfried Domscheit' comment
Edit2: Added second solution with trunc

Comment: You must use `TRUNC` instead of `ROUND`, otherwise the boundaries are wrong. Verify by adding `min(MY_DATE), max(MY_DATE)`

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit : Absolutely, rookie mistake i did. Edited the answer. thx

Comment: Thanks a lot for the query , but  you have mentioned  to use TRUNC instead of ROUND  but I do not see the round function in the query .Can you please take a look once .

Comment: I added the trunc version. They give the same result but the trunc one is indeed clearer. I must have been tired when i thought about the first one :)

Comment: Missed your comment that you have changed the round by Floor . The query is just one word to represent 'Awesome ". Thanks again

Comment: @AurobrataRoyChowdhury Use the Round version though :) it's much clearer and probably much performant too